# On page refresh the nested JSON object is throwing error while computing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```
const { trips, loading} = useContext(TripContext);

trips:[
  {
    "tripMetaData": {
      "dispatchTareWt": "321",
      "dispatchGrossWt": "21213",
    },
    "createdAt": "2021-04-14 12:07:00"
  },
  {
    "tripMetaData": {
      "dispatchTareWt": "11",
      "dispatchGrossWt": "33",
    },
    "createdAt": "2021-04-14 11:38:27"
  },
]

   function getjson(){

  if (trips.length && !loading){
  
  let res = Object.values(trips.reduce((acc,curr)=>
  {(acc[moment(curr.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')] = acc[moment(curr.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY')] || {name: moment(curr.createdAt).format('DD/MM/YYYY'), value: 0}).value += (parseInt(curr.tripMetaData.dispatchGrossWt)-parseInt(curr.tripMetaData.dispatchTareWt));
   return acc;}, {}));
   return res;
  }
}
```

I have this JSON object trips which I am getting it from a context object and a getjson function. Problem is when I am refreshing my react page it throws "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchGrossWt' of undefined". Normally on page load this works fine but problem occurs on page refresh. I tried

```
return (
  trips.length && !loading &&
    <> my components here </>
```

but this approach is not working aswell

Answer (score 0):

`trips.map(()=>trips.tripMetaData).length` is not the proper way to get the number of trips. `trips` is already a table, so you can apply the `length` property directly on it: `trips.length`.

Then, if you want to work on each trip, you can do:

```js
trips.map(trip => trip.tripMetaData); // This will return the detail of each trip.
```

Comment: have edited the question, but it still doesn't work

Comment: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'dispatchGrossWt' of undefined", but it only happens when I refresh my page

Comment: So we're moving forward... I think that you should add a condition in your `reduce`: like `if (curr.tripMetaData)` then you can perform your operation. There must be a reason why your trips variable is empty when you reload the page but I can't tell why with just these informations.

Comment: this worked , thanks Romain. did some random length checks on the json and it worked

Comment: You're welcome. Perhaps can you validate the answer...